# HTML5 - Android Screen Size

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, screen

I am creating a web app for android phones(HTML 5) using jquery mobile. Just want to know what should be my width and length of the page so that it will fit in all phones with different screen resolutions.

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this article: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/an-introduction-to-meta-viewport-and-viewport/. There you will find everything about HTML viewport meta tag and how it is used resolution handling.

Tag example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height">
```

You would also want to look at css media syntax, it will help you to better suite your content do different resolutions.

Then there's this article about layout optimization : http://www.slideshare.net/andreasbovens/optimizing-your-layout-for-phones-and-tablets-using-viewport-and-media-queries. It is an excellent presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Twitter BootStrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) to design your html5 pages and the css defined in it will take care of all the screen sizes.

Check [This](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html)